# How to turn-on laptop's battery pack after replacing cells?

Tags: dc, lithium-ion, batteries

After a few years of use, my battery pack finally died. The laptop doesn't even detect or try to charge the pack anymore.
So I replaced the cells in the pack for new ones, but that didn't make it to come to life again. I tested the pack's end terminals to see if there is voltage, but there is no voltage at all.
If I connect the pack into the laptop, it's not detected either.

The pack has what it seems to be a built-in charge indicator. When I press the button on the left, the first LED blinks for 3 seconds, that's all.
[image]

I followed the intructions in [here](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_repair_a_laptop_battery) to try to revive the pack:

> Connecting the voltmeter to the outer terminals, take a 100-Ohm resistor, tie one end to ground, and with the other end touch each terminal while observing the voltmeter

But had no success.

Is there something else I can do to bring the pack back to life?

**Hardware details:**
Laptop: HP Omnibook vt6200
Battery pack: 14.8V (8 x 18650 cells)

Comment: Either your wiring is bad, something died, or the batteries are empty enough that the charger won't charge them.

Comment: @Passerby : or more likely there is some intelligence in the battery pack that has detected abnormality and requires resetting. I had the same problem after replacing cells in a Sony Vaio battery pack. I'm pretty confident in my wiring, but less so in hacking the undocumented ICs in there! (And yes I *am* annoyed that things seem to be designed to actively oppose their maintenance nowadays)

Comment: I have replaced the cells in LiPo batteries before and always had them power up turned OFF.  The way I turned them back on again was to force a small amount of current back into the battery pack output terminals.  Exactly as if I were charging the pack.  That did the trick on the few packs that I have rebuilt.  YMMV

Comment: @GetFree, Dwayne Reid's technique sounds like the same as my edit to my answer.  Good luck

Comment: @getfree Finally, did you manage to make it work? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Every laptop battery pack that I have taken apart has had a battery management chip connected to it.  It is impossible to miss as it typically runs the length of the battery pack and packaged with the battery inside the pack.  Quite often when I take apart a 'dead' laptop battery pack and test the cells inside, they are all still in reasonable shape.  I reason from that finding that it must be the battery management chip or BMS that has died telling the computer that the battery is no longer any good.

Perhaps this happened to your battery, or, when you were repacking your battery, you damaged the BMS, or you rewired it incorrectly.  It is very easy to damage those chips.  Also, those chips need to turned on after they have lost power.  It sounds like you tried to with the resistor idea,  but it didn't work.  So either that is not how you turn on or wake up your particular chip, or you damaged your chip or wired it incorrectly.

When you took the pack apart did you see the little thermistor taped to one of the batteries?  I believe that some batteries automatically turn off if their thermistor (thermometor) is not giving them a reading.

So there are plenty of reasons why it won't charge.  From your description, your BMS has not been turned on or woken up and is that because it is incorrectly wired, burned out, or physically damaged by your repacking?

Good luck.

Edit: As far as waking up your BMS, I have never tried to wake up a laptop's BMS.  I have woken up many other BMS by appying a very small current to the terminals as if I was going to charge it.  The small current applied is at the battery pack's charge voltage, but not to the battery terminals thenselves, but the terminals of the pack, which will also be the terminals that the BMS runs through I.E., you are applying the current through the BMS to the battery.  So for your 14.8 nominal pack, what was the voltage of the individual cells when you repacked them? Let's assume they were exactly 3.7 volts x 4 in series gives you the 14.8 volts.  So apply a very small current (a couple hundred milliamps or way less) at 14.9 volts.  If your pack is sitting at 16 volts at the moment, then apply the current at 16.1 volts or even 16 volts.  Don't go over 16.8 volts regardless and be ready for smoking and burning that tells you your BMS is no good!