# No voltage at battery terminals

Tags: batteries, i2c, laptop, smbus

I replaced the cells on my Laptop unfortunately disconnected BMS while doing so.
HP battery check says each cell voltage and Temp correctly and calibration warning but can't calibrate as no terminal voltage. already tried the resistor method but in vain.
the charging indicator goes orange for 8 sec then white. windows shows 0% plugged in. left it overnight but nothing happened. didn't charge.
battery is OA04 4 cells couldn't read BMS IC etched markings they're not clear to read.
Already tried some I2C codes but they showed wrong data.
battery pin out (1 +,2 +,3 SMBus Data,4 SMBus Clock,5 BatID,6 TEMP,7 -,8 -)
https://pinoutguide.com/Power/HP_envy-pavilion_dv6_pinout.shtml
Help
edit: Hp uses two bms one in battery the other on the board. It activates the battery through codes not high or low signal that's why jumpering power didn't work. Bms is working though I can read battery data and voltage but it's locked because it sees capacity below 25% or that's what I think.
2: it charged for a minute then the indicator blinks whitewhen I insulated SMData as in here https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/HP-Battery-Alert/m-p/2597653/highlight/true#M348632

Comment: Check connection between cells

Comment: Did you read here? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/167084/how-to-turn-on-laptops-battery-pack-after-replacing-cells

Comment: @fraxinus that's quite the problem. wake the bms. I'm asking how

Comment: @user263983 solid. it reads every cell properly.